# Input field readonly without making the input-addon button readonly

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When I make the input field readonly, it automatically makes the button in input-group-addon also readonly.

Below is the code:

```
<div class="input-group date" id="dt_{{$id}}" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !$valid }">

    <input type="text" readonly id="date-input_{{$id}}" class="form-control" ng-model="inputValue" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>

</div>
```

How can I make the input field read-only without making the button since I am unable to use the same.

Comment: why you are trying to make the input field readonly ? It's supposed to take the inputs. how about directly displaying the text ?

Comment: It needs to be made read only coz its a date picker and i want the user to select date and not manually change the date

Comment: Without the read-only are you getting datepicker with this code? Won't you need to use `<input type="date">`?

Comment: Yes without read-only I am able to see and use date picker properly